Kotlin deserializing from either a list or string
i'm using ktor to get a json response like
{
    "status": "success"
    "response": [
        {
        "v1": 1,
        "v2": {...}
        },
        {
        "v1": "0",
        "v2": {...}
        },
    ]
}

and i want to deserialize it to this
@Serializable
data class a(
    val status: String,
    @Serializable(with = ResponseSerializer::class)
    val response: ResponseType,
)

@Serializable
data class Response(
    val v1: JsonPrimitive, // can be string or int
    val v2: c
)

@Serializable
data class c(
...
)

I tried doing this but i'm getting kotlinx.serialization.json.internal.JsonDecodingException: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject (Kotlin reflection is not available) as the serialized body of ResponseList, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonArray (Kotlin reflection is not available)
sealed class ResponseType

@Serializable
data class ResponseString(val value: String) : ResponseType()

@Serializable
data class ResponseList(val value: List<Response>) : ResponseType()

object ResponseSerializer : JsonContentPolymorphicSerializer<ResponseType>(ResponseType::class) {
    override fun selectDeserializer(element: JsonElement): DeserializationStrategy<ResponseType> =
        when {
            element is JsonPrimitive && element.isString -> ResponseString.serializer()
            else -> ResponseList.serializer()
        }
}

and in the httpclient i have
install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json {
                serializersModule = SerializersModule {
                    polymorphic(ResponseType::class) {
                        subclass(ResponseString::class)
                        subclass(ResponseList::class)
                    }
                }
            })
        }

what else do i need? it seems i can do like
val response: JsonElement
when (val res = a.response) {
               val j = Json
                is JsonArray -> {
                    val a = j.decodeFromJsonElement<List<Response>>(res)
                }
                else -> ...
            }

but i dont know if its right

Please [edit] and provide a [mre].

Can you give a JSON example you are to deserialize?

Can you update the question with the JSON instead of writing it in a comment?

The problem is that you have a type mismatch. When the object {"v1": 1, "v2": {...}} is encountered by the deserializer, it tries to apply the deserializer of the ResponseList class. To solve this problem, you don't need a custom serializer, so the property with the JsonPrimitive type should suffice.
fun main() {
    val result = Json.decodeFromString<a>(
        """
        {
            "status": "success",
            "response": [
                {"v1": 1},
                {"v1": "0"}
            ]
        }
    """.trimIndent()
    )

    for (r in result.response) {
        println(r.v1)
    }
}

@Serializable
data class a(
    val status: String,
    val response: List<Response>,
)

@Serializable
class Response(
    val v1: JsonPrimitive
)


response can also be a string. i gave example of when it's a list only
